# Differentiating this trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Differentiating
$$
L = \frac{2v_o^2\cos^2\theta}{g\cos\alpha}\cdot(\tan\theta-\tan\alpha)
$$

with regard to theta. I know I have to use trig. idendities, but I'm just completely stuck.

Comment: You will need to know the product rule as well as the derivatives of $\cos^2\theta$ and $\tan\theta$.

Comment: $-2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$, yeah. I just don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$(f(\theta)g(\theta))'=f'(\theta)g(\theta)+f(\theta)g'(\theta)$$
where 
$$f(\theta)=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}\cos^2\theta,\ \ g(\theta)=\tan\theta-\tan\alpha.$$

Hence, we have
$$\begin{align}\frac{dL}{d\theta}&=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}(-2\cos\theta\sin\theta)(\tan\theta-\tan\alpha)+\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}\cos^2\theta\cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\\&=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}(-2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}-\tan\alpha\right)+\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}\\&=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}(-2\sin^2\theta+2\cos\theta\sin\theta\tan\alpha)+\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}\\&=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}(\color{blue}{-2\sin^2\theta}+\color{red}{2\cos\theta\sin\theta}\tan\alpha\color{blue}{+1})\\&=\frac{2v_0^2}{g\cos\alpha}(\color{red}{\sin(2\theta)}\tan\alpha+\color{blue}{\cos(2\theta)}).\end{align}$$

Comment: I got that part down. It's just the simplifying afterwards I can't do.

Comment: @Gliffie: Ok, first, please write $f'(\theta)$ and $g'(\theta)$.

Comment: $\frac{2v_o^2}{g\cos\alpha}(-2\sin\theta\cos\theta)$ and $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$

Comment: @Gliffie: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Gliffie: You are welcome!